# Laravel routing intercepts all requests to js files etc

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel and I've been having a few problems setting up the dev environment for Laravel.

I'm using the Built in PHP web server on windows. Which I've started either with:

```
php artisan serve
```

or 
    php -S localhost:8000 server.php

I'm basically trying to get css and js served correctly, unfortunately the Laravel routing seems to be getting in the way. I initially rewrote the server.php file to not run on requests ending in .js, css etc.

However this requires me to suffix any src URLs with public which is not really sensible.

I've seen quite a few tutorials about how Laravel Elixir writes the SASS and minified js files to the public folder which looks perfectly fine but I can't get past this routing issue.

What am I missing? I've seen very few details about this so not sure what I've done wrong here.

Note I'm trying to get this working so a dev team can use this so ideally I'd like to avoid complex aliases etc. Which could easily be setup in a live environment but in a team it becomes painful and I can imagine people being tempted to hack the server.php file or similar horrors.

Thanks,

Comment: run `php -S localhost:8000` inside public folder

Comment: Can you verify that your server.php is unadulterated? Original here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/server.php

Comment: Thanks - If I do this then server.php is not loaded I presume?. Suggestion 1 seems to work. This is not documented anywhere, is it definitely the right approach? Was thinking as the artisan file in the root folder then I should run it from this point?